# How to perform firebase authentication that returns a flow in android kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

**What I currently have**:

- I have a service class where I perform firebase registration for a
  user.
- It is working.

**What I am trying to do**:

- I am trying to return a flow

**Current code**:

```
class LoginService @Inject constructor(
    // This contains the firebase auth reference
    val service : FirebaseAuthRepository
) {

    private fun registerUser(
        firstName:String, lastName:String,
        email:String, password:String
    ) {
        // Create an instance and create a register a user with email and password.
        service.getFirebaseAuth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                // If the registration is successfully done
                if (task.isSuccessful) {

                    // Firebase registered user
                    task.result.user?.let { firebaseUser ->
                        // Instance of User data model class.
                        val user = User(firebaseUser.uid, firstName, lastName, email)

                        // Pass the required values in the constructor.
                        //FirestoreClass().registerUser(this@RegisterActivity, user)
                    }
                } else {
                    // Error
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you intend to implement Firebase sign-in with Google, then I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) might help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Answer (score 0):

You can use kotlin [callbackFlow](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html).